# Does OnResume() in Android makes Activity loading faster?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-database

I was developing an Android Application where I have to load a large data from Android Database and view it on screen.

In earlier stages of development I used to retrieve data from DB in OnCreate() method and it really slowed the start of activity when data became huge. So I called the retrieving of data and viewing it on screen in OnResume() method, so that my app does not crash while taking too long to load it.
I know activity is not shown until OnResume is completed.

**So is it a good approach to call time taking operations in OnResume instead of having all initialization in OnCreate() method?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So is it a good approach to call time taking operations in OnResume instead of having all initialization in OnCreate() method?

no - you should not do it inside OnCreate or OnResume. You should always do it inside working thread - like AsyncTask.

Any opertion that takes to long to finish, if executed on UI thread will block message queue - this means there are no repaint of UI widgets, user cannot tap on your app to do anything. Everything is blocked until your operation finished. After ~5s Android generates ANR (application is not responding) and kills your app.

Answer (score 1):

You should never do IO operations on the main thread. This includes `onCreate` and `onResume` methods, which will always be called on the main thread.

To correctly load data you should either use an **AsyncTask** or the **ContentLoader** with its callbacks.

Generally speaking, to use a database with your application you should use a `ContentProvider` and `CursorLoader`s. There are plenty of tutorials on how to use these and it makes your code better manageable.